# Android Application Distribution / Upgrade

Tags: android, google-plus, transfer

In regards to app transfer process, has anyone experienced difficulties after a transfer of ownership was done?

We are developing an app for a client, who have an existing app being hosted and managed by a 3rd party vendor. We need to understand the process of helping the client get ownership of the current app and then with the same name of the app, push our (new) binaries as an update to the app. The key thing is that there should not be any disruption to the current service and the transition to the new app is transparent to the users – All reviews, ratings etc. remain the same.

- What are the key information transfers that must happen during transfer of ownership of an app (Keys, version no. etc.)?
- If new update to an app is completely different in architecture, is there an approval process from Google Play to go through? If yes, how long does this usually take?

So to summarize, ‘V’ is the third party vendor hosting the app named ‘X’ for our client ‘C’. We (Dev company ‘D’) want to replace the current app with our implementation, but retaining the existing app name, customer base, reviews, ratings etc. such that existing users just get a notification to upgrade their existing app and it changes to the new app once they download.

Thanks!

Comment: bullet point 2 - no. For the rest i f you are "professional"  why don't you do a test run and create v2, x2, c2, d. And use d to move x2 from v2 to c2.